# Javascript overwriting a variable inside setTimeout anon function

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, settimeout

I'm trying to overwrite a variable using a global variable from within a function, however, it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

I want the end result in test2 to log "after". It's currently logging "before".

If I remove the setTimeout it works, however, I need a setTimeout in the code.

```js
var jeff = "before";

function test() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jeff = "after";
    test();
  }, 1000);
}

test();

function test2() {
  console.log(jeff);
}

test2();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because it is asynchronous.... the code does not wait until the setTimeout runs.... Bascially you ordered a pizza and as soon as you hang up the phone you try to eat the pizza. It has yet to be made and delivered.

Comment: Because it's not getting set for a full second, but you're calling it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you will get this to work is if you cause the `console.log`or a function that calls `console.log` to happen during or after the timeout.

For example:

```js
var jeff = "before";

function test() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jeff = "after";
    test2();
  }, 1000);
}

test();

function test2() {
  console.log(jeff);
}
```

Comment: I ended up fixing it myself like this after reading through the comments. Don't know how I missed this to be honest, I should probably go to bed now haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments say, the code doesn't wait, it runs asynchronous.

You have 2 options:

1) Use a `setTimeout` in the `test2()` function, like so:

```
function test2() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(jeff);
   }, 1000);
}
```

2) Or use a `setTimeout` when calling `test2()`, like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(jeff);
}, 1000);
```

Both of these will act exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

As commenters are pointing out, the setTimeout causes that block of code (the setTimeout callback function) to run asynchronously, which means that the main “thread” (sorry if that’s not the proper term here) continues to run without it, which in your case is the execution of `test1()` and `test2()`. Obviously that all happens in less than 1000 milliseconds, so your global variable is still “before”.

HOWEVER, there is more going on here: try changing the timeout to 0. You’ll notice that it still doesn’t work. That is because asynchronous code must wait in a queue before it has a chance to be executed. The main “thread” will still continue running without it, because it’s as if there are two criteria for running code within that setTimeout: 1. The specified milliseconds must have passed, and 2. the thread/stack/thing shouldn’t be busy. If it is busy when the time is up, your code will still have to wait until the event loop comes back around another time with a free hand to execute that code.

Sorry if the technical jargon isn’t exact. I think conceptually that should be very helpful. Here is an excellent video which will give you a look under the hood: https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0